# Does insider trading extend to physical goods (not equities)?

Tags: hypothetical, sale-of-goods, insider-trading

Any jurisdiction is fair game, but I’m interested in the United States

If one has insider information that would meaningfully influence their choice to buy/sell a stock, there might be restrictions on when they can trade.

However, does that apply to goods, such as vehicles? Imagine someone areas going to purchase a car for $X, but they learn (via legally obtained insider information) that the company is planning to drop the car price by, say, 20%. Are there any restrictions on them buying the car there?

Or, for a slightly different example, if someone was buying cars (legally) to resell them, and they had insider info that car prices from a company would rise by 20%, would it be illegal for them to purchase ahead of the rise when they otherwise wouldn’t have?

Answer (score 2):

### No

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The crime is defined in s1043A of the Corporations Act applies only to financial products which includes include securities, derivatives, interests in managed funds, stocks, bonds and superannuation products.